Horizontal line between categories in Agenda
Consider this agenda custom command:
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("u" "Unscheduled Tasks."
           todo ""
           ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy '((category-up)))
            (org-agenda-todo-ignore-with-date t)))))

It picks up all TODOs that do not have an attached timestamp and sorts it based on categories.
Is it possible to have a horizontal line after each category? That will make it easier to read.
Also, is there a better way to implement org-agenda-todo-ignore-with-date? I remember reading some other notation using ':'

Rather than modifying the output of the agenda buffer by using something like the finalization hook, one idea might be to create a task for each category and use it like a divider line -- here is an example of a task that I use for dividing tasks based (in part) on sorting by priority and alphabetically:  ** Active [#A] .;;;;;;;;;;; TOP ;;;;;;;;;;;. :TOP:@home:

There is no user-accessible way to do that (e.g. there is no option that you can customize to do that). The closest you can come is to add an after-advice to org-agenda-finalize-entries which returns the string that org-todo-list inserts into the agenda buffer. You'd have to parse that string in the after-advice and figure out where to add the separators before returning the final string to org-todo-list.l

@lawlist Thanks. That is a quick and useful hack. Does not look pretty. But works.
